# Converting SQL to LINQ With Sub Query

Tags: sql, linq

I am struggling in converting following SQL to LINQ. Can anyone help me please :

```
   
 SELECT M.Id, M.borrower_id, M.application_id,  [borrower_first_name] ,[borrower_last_name], DP.ID, DP.masterline_id, PR.ID, PR.masterline_id
  FROM [dbo].[CCMemberizationPII] AS M
         LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT  MAX(DP.ID) ID, DP.masterline_id
          FROM [dbo].[CCDailyPositions] AS DP 
          GROUP BY DP.masterline_id) DP
       ON DP.masterline_id = M.application_id
        LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT  MAX(PR.ID) ID, PR.masterline_id
          FROM [dbo].[CCPurchase] AS PR
          GROUP BY PR.masterline_id) PR
       ON PR.masterline_id = M.application_id 
  order by M.Id
```

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building LINQ query, try do decompose parts for building final query.

```cs
var positions = 
    from dp in ctx.CCDailyPositions
    group by new { dp.masterline_id } into g
    select new 
    {
        ID = g.Max(x => x.ID),
        dp.masterline_id
    };

var purchases = 
    from pr in ctx.CCPurchase
    group by new { pr.masterline_id } into g
    select new 
    {
        ID = g.Max(x => x.ID),
        pr.masterline_id
    };

var query = 
    from m in ctx.CCMemberizationPII
    from dp in positions.Where(dp => dp.masterline_id == m.application_id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pr in purchases.Where(pr => pr.masterline_id == m.application_id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby m.Id
    select new 
    {
        m.Id, 
        m.borrower_id, 
        m.application_id,  
        m.borrower_first_name,
        m.borrower_last_name, 
        DP_ID = dp.ID, 
        PR_ID = pr.ID, 
    };
```

Also your query can be written using `OUTER APPLY`. Note that EF Core can transform OUTER APPLY to LEFT JOIN with Window Function usage.

```cs
var query = 
    from m in ctx.CCMemberizationPII
    from dp in ctx.CCDailyPositions.Where(dp => dp.masterline_id == m.application_id)
        .OrderByDescending(dp => dp.ID)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pr in ctx.CCPurchase.Where(pr => pr.masterline_id == m.application_id)
        .OrderByDescending(pr => pr.ID)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby m.Id
    select new 
    {
        m.Id, 
        m.borrower_id, 
        m.application_id,  
        m.borrower_first_name,
        m.borrower_last_name, 
        DP_ID = dp.ID, 
        PR_ID = pr.ID, 
    };
```

Which SQL will be better, depends on execution plan in your particular case.

Comment: I ended up using the OUTER APPLY. I am getting same results from SQL and LINQ in LINQPad. Can you please refer me to any site where I can learn about this OUTER APPLY. I can write SQL but finding it hard to translate it into LINQ. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you need? How to express OUTER APPLY by LINQ or what is OUTER APPLY?

Comment: How to express OUTER APPLY by LINQ!